# Isolate product names from strings by matching string after (including) first letter in a variable

Tags: string, bash, letter

I have a bunch of strings of following pattern in a text file:

```
201194_2012110634 Appliance 130 AB i Some optional (Notes )
300723_2017050006(2016111550) Device 16 AB i Note
```

The first part is serial, the second is date. Device/Appliance name and model (about 10 possible different names) is the string after date number and before (including `AB i`).

I was able to isolate dates and serials using

```
SERIAL=${line:0:6}
YEAR=${line:7:4}
```

I'm trying to isolate Device name and note after that:

```
#!/bin/bash
while IFS= read line || [[ -n $line ]]; do
  NAME=${line#*[a-zA-Z]}
  STRINGAP='Appliance '"${line/#*Appliance/}"
```

The first approach is to take everything after the first letter appearing in line, which gives me

```
NAME = ppliance 130 AB i Some optional (Notes )
```

The second approach is to write tests for each of the ~10 possible appliance/device names and then append appliance name after the subtracted test. Then test variable which actually matched Appliance / Device (or other name) and use that to input into the database.

Is it possible to write a line that would select everything, including first letter in a line, in text file? Then I would subtract everything after `AB i` to get notes and everything before `AB i` would become appliance name.

Comment: please edit your Q to show your required output for your 2 sample input records. Use the `{}` option in the edit tool bar on your selected text to have it format correctly. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the ${line#*[az-A-Z]} line (which will, as you see, remove the first character of the name), and instead use

```
STRINGAP=$(echo "$line" | sed 's/^[0-9_]* \(.*\) AB i.*/\1/')
```

This drops the leading digits and underscore, and everything from " AB i" to the end.

Edit: The details are unclear - do you want to keep the "AB i", and will it always be "AB i"? If you want it, change the line to

```
STRINGAP=$(echo "$line" | sed 's/^[0-9_]* \(.* AB i\).*/\1/')
```

I also forgot the double quotes round the text line.

Comment: I started from your answer as it does what I need quickly. I modified your line a bit and it now fails only in 3/43 test cases (dataset is around 1600 lines) which use wrong naming convention. `NAME=$(echo "$line" | sed 's/^[0-9_]*[(a-z 0-9)]* \([A-Z]*.* AB i\).*/\1/')` The [(a-z 0-9)]* catches any brackets additional numbers in them and comments appearing in lines of `300723_2017050006(2016111550) Device 16 AB i Note` format the [A-Z]* catches the start of Appliance name which is always in capital. This catches 93% of cases so it's good enough for now.

Comment: The final line is `NAME=$(echo "$line" | sed 's/^[0-9_]*[(a-z 0-9)]*[ _]\([A-Z]*.* AB[ ]*i\).*/\1/')` it accounts for lines where there is a space between ABi and where there isn't one. It gets 97% of lines correctly on a 100 line sample.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sed` and `read` to give you more control of parsing.

```
tmp> line2="300723_2017050006(2016111550) Device 16 AB i Note"
tmp> read serial date type val <<<$(echo $line2 | \
         sed 's/\([0-9]*\)_\([0-9]*\)[^A-Z]*\(Device\|Appliance\) \
         \([0-9]*\).*/\1 \2 \3 \4/')
tmp> echo "$serial|$date|$type|$val"
300723|2017050006|Device|16
```

Basically, read allows you to assign multiple variables in one line.   The sed statment parses the line, and gives you space delimitted output of its results.   You can also read each variable seperately if you don't mind running sed a few extra times:

```
 device="$(echo $line2 | sed -e 's/^.*Device \([0-9]*\).*/\1/;t;d')"
 appliance="$(echo $line2 | sed -e 's/^.*Appliance \([0-9]*\).*/\1/;t;d')"
```

This way `$device` is populated with device if present, and is blank otherwise (note the `-e` and `;t;d` at the end of the regex to prevent it from dumping the line if it doesn't match.)

Answer (score 1):

Your question isn't clear but it seems like you might be trying to parse strings  into substrings. Try this with GNU awk for the 3rd arg to match() and let us know if there's something else you were looking for:

```
$ awk 'match($0,/^([0-9]+)_([0-9]+)(\([0-9]+\))?\s+(\S+)\s+(\S+)\s+(\S+)\s+(\S+)\s+(.*)/,a) {
    for (i=1; i<=8; i++) {
        print i, a[i]
    }
    print "---"
}' file
1 201194
2 2012110634
3
4 Appliance
5 130
6 AB
7 i
8 Some optional (Notes )
---
1 300723
2 2017050006
3 (2016111550)
4 Device
5 16
6 AB
7 i
8 Note
---
```

If you wanted a CSV output, for example, then it'd just be:

```
$ awk -v OFS=',' 'match($0,/^([0-9]+)_([0-9]+)(\([0-9]+\))?\s+(\S+)\s+(\S+)\s+(\S+)\s+(\S+)\s+(.*)/,a) {
    for (i=1; i<=8; i++) {
        printf "%s%s", a[i], (i<8?OFS:ORS)
    }
}' file
201194,2012110634,,Appliance,130,AB,i,Some optional (Notes )
300723,2017050006,(2016111550),Device,16,AB,i,Note
```

Massage to suit...